# Flask with Jinja2 - Passing value from Flask to Javascript using Jinja2 statements

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

This is my code in Flask

```
data = {"Bird" : "Its a bird!"}
@app.route('/store')
def store():
    return render_template('store.html', data = data)
```

This is my code in Javascript

```
<script>
  var val = "Bird";
  var something = '{{ data[' + val +'] }}';
</script>
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but I cant seem to get `something` to be `"Its a bird!"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your template, try `var d = {{ data|safe }}` and then access like this `d["Bird"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that Jinja2 template rendering happens *before* the JavaScript is executed. You can see this in the fact that you render the template and then return it to the user (or their browser).

Therefore, anything that comes out of that template render process, must be valid JavaScript in order to run. Also, Jinja2 does not know anything about HTML, JavaScript or really any other language.

Putting this knowledge into use would basically mean that you need to render the required data into valid JavaScript:

```
<script>
  var mapping = {{ data | tojson }};
  var val = "Bird";
  var something = mapping[val];
</script>
```

Personally, however, I would avoid templating JavaScript code and figure out some other way or handling dynamic data.